# How to do spaces between text/components for JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
    JRadioButton choice1 = new JRadioButton ("Daytime (6:00 A.M. through 5:59 P.M.)"+"$0.07");
    choice1.setActionCommand("0.07");

    JRadioButton choice2 = new JRadioButton ("Evening (6:00 P.M. through 11:59 P.M.)"+"$0.12");
    choice2.setActionCommand("0.12");

    JRadioButton choice3 = new JRadioButton ("Off-Peak (12:00 A.M. through 5:59 A.M.)"+"$0.05");
    choice3.setActionCommand("0.05");

    JButton calculate = new JButton ("Calculate");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(choice1);
    group.add(choice2);
    group.add(choice3);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel.add(choice1);
    panel.add(choice2);
    panel.add(choice3);
    panel.add(calculate);
    JLabel result = new JLabel("Total Cost is: ");
    panel.add(result);
    window.add(panel);

    window.setVisible(true);
```

As you see, I created a JPanel that has a group of RadioButtons that gives 3 choices to pick. What I'm creating is a phone call payment list. I want to have spaces between my time intervals and the fees corresponding to them. For example, having word "Daytime(6:00 A.M. through 5:59 P.M)" appear on the very left, and value "$0.07" on the very right of the window. How would I do that? Thanks very much!

Comment: did you try to make them in a JLabel?

Comment: You need to take the values in two different components for eg `JLabel` and then you can use `BorderLayout.CONSTANTS` to set the positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible by keeping it the text from the `JRadioButton` but if you make an appart `JLabel` for the fee, it should be ok.

[`JLabel#setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment(int)) takes a `JLabel` constant as argument and you can align your text to the `JLabel.LEFT`, `JLabel.RIGHT` or `JLabel.CENTER`.

Here is the output you could expect, it is up to you to find the perfect Layout for your program of course

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much bro! Why did I not think of this before!! :D

Comment: now I did this first: `JLabel payment1 = new JLabel ("$0.07");`

Comment: and then on the bottom 'panel.add(payment1);
  payment1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.NORTH);'

Comment: I mean `panel.add(payment1);
     payment1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.NORTH);` but for some reason it doesn't let you run

Comment: Why would you need `SwingConstants.NORTH` ? Use `JLabel.RIGHT` because it is horizontal not vertical, so no need for North here :). And try putting it before adding payment1 to the panel.

Comment: I tried JLabel.Left, JLabel.Top, etc. It seems like nothing had changed with my statements added there.

Comment: maybe I should do something with my JRadioButtons first to make the button and label both on the same line?